# New row when limit on row reached with mysqli while php

Tags: php, mysqli, max, row

so I have a little row setup with a mysqli echoing system so I can paste out the information I want in the little boxes I have in a row. I want four columns and those should be filled (if they're not, they will just be filled with other boxes). Now, when that limit is reached, I want a new row to  be started on. In theory it should be easy..  but I can't figure it out.

Can you?

```
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM as_sound LEFT JOIN as_account ON as_account.id = as_sound.poster_id ");
                        $counter = 0;
                        $max = 4;

                        echo "<div class='row'>";

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                                while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) and ($counter < $max)){

                                    echo " <div class='column'>
                                                <div class='item'>
                                                    <a class='item-link' href='#'><img src='images/test.jpg' alt='header-image' width='346' ></a>
                                                    <p class='sound-title'><a class='item-link' href='#'>" . $row['name'] ."</p></a>
                                                    <table style='width:100%'>
                                                    <td><a class='item-link' href='#'><p class='sound-desc'>" . $row['short_desc'] ."</p></a></td>
                                                    <td><a class='item-link' href='#'><div class='item-avatar'><img src='" . $row['avatarimg'] . "' alt='Avatar'></a></div>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <div class='price'>$" . $row['price'] . "</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>"; 

                                            $counter++; }}

                    echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how many things you've output:

```
$col = 1;

while(...) {
   $col++;
   if ($col > $col_limit) {
      ... end previous column
      ... start new column
      $col = 0;
   }
   ... output column
}
```

Comment: mind putting it in the code? Don't quite understand how or where to put it in to make it work.. Sorry for being an absolute knob.

Answer (score 0):

Preview (simulated data): https://jsfiddle.net/mf7qd5gn/

```
$sql     = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM as_sound LEFT JOIN as_account ON as_account.id = as_sound.poster_id ");
$counter = 0;
$max     = 4;

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        if ($counter % $max == 0) {
            echo "<div class='row'>";
        }
        echo " <div class='column'>
                        <div class='item'>
                            <a class='item-link' href='#'><img src='images/test.jpg' alt='header-image' width='346' /></a>
                            <p class='sound-title'><a class='item-link' href='#'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></p>
                            <table style='width:100%'>
                            <tr>
                            <td><a class='item-link' href='#'><p class='sound-desc'>" . $row['short_desc'] . "</p></a></td>
                            <td><a class='item-link' href='#'><div class='item-avatar'><img src='" . $row['avatarimg'] . "' alt='Avatar' /></div></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class='price'>$" . $row['price'] . "</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
        $counter++;
        if ($counter % $max == 0) {
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't work.. it won't echo the other parts round for some reason, just the price.

Comment: ah.. now I see. Well, the problem is that I want three collumns on one row. This echoes out every object on a single row - which  isn't optimal. Basically, this is what I want (ignore last row) and then it should repeat until the limit is filled from the mysqli query (which is set at 12 atm)

Comment: uh, I'm kidding... uh.. Okay, so I have now 5 items in my database and the fitfh looks like this when a new row is made http://i.gyazo.com/982300a485e8d4ac581b6ad5e0b7a9f3.png